# Count unique values single column pandas

Tags: pandas, count, pandas-groupby

Hi I have the following dataframe and I want to count the number of times that each year repeats

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1958,1963,1958,1963],'title':['a','g','z','e']})
```

How can I group by the year and count how many times each year is? I would create an additional column with the count.

Answer (score 2):

Check with `value_counts`

```
out = df['year'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Great thanks! extremely simple! I cant believe it :)